# Android Studio Build error 'ExecutionException'

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm having a problem building up my android studio project. I've cloned the git repository and added the keystore path and password correctly as I do in all projects, but this time I've got the following error. Anyone have any idea what it can be?

[image: PRINT ERROR]

Comment: show full `build.gradle`

Comment: Update your `compile com.android.tools.build:gradle:+` to latest version

Comment: And look at the Gradle console for the full error message

Answer (score 0):

Due to many reasons this error comes. Try below options :

1. Update to latest version.
2. Check whether XML files tag are properly closed.
3. Delete cache data from your system
4. Check whether android SDK build tools installed or not
5. If installed, Change the appcompat dependency version and make project